# Make HTML element overlay navbar in Material Design

Tags: html, css, material-design

I'm trying to get a `div` to overlap the default NavBar from Material Design. I've tried by giving my div a high Z-index but without luck.

You can [find a Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/vEC5pz5GABnkfognGZRP?p=preview). My goal is simply to have the green Box complete overlay the NavBar

CSS:

```
#overlay {
  background-color:green;
  height:200px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
      <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div id="overlay">Overlay</div>
  </main>
</div>

</html>
```